# Indicate combobox values with a specific ids?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I made a Sub that will populate my combobox with loan descriptions. I want to get the `loancode` of the `loandescription` on `selectedindexchanged` without querying again the database. Is this possible? Or should I query the database to get the indicated `loancode`?

```
Private Sub LoanProducts()
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT loancode,loandescription FROM LoanProducts", gSQlConn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        dt.Clear()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            CmbLoanAvail.Items.Add(row("loandescription"))
        Next row
    End Using
End Sub
```

**Expected output:**

Everytime the combobox index changed, the loancode of the selected loandescription will be displayed to a textbox.

Comment: Use the `DataTable` as the DataSource of your ComboBox. Set the `DisplayMember` property  to the `loandescription` Column and the `ValueMember` property to the `loancode` Column. When an Item is selected, get the `SelectedValue` and cast it to he type of `loancode`.

Comment: @Jimi can you post your answer below?

Comment: You can not get the value if you only fill the description in the combo box without querying in the database.

Comment: You haven't specified a platform. A ComboBox can be a WinForms, WPF, UWP, Office/VBA control (more...)

Comment: @jimi windows forms

Comment: @jzoler You do not need to query database to get the selected value, only you need to change the definition i.e., assign the value member also to the combo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `DataTable` to combobox `.DataSource` property and populate `.ValueMember` and .`DisplayMember` properties with corresponding column names.

```
Private Sub LoanProducts()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT loancode, loandescription FROM LoanProducts"
    Using command As New SqlCommand(query, gSQlConn)
        Dim data As New DataTable
        Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter With
        {
            .SelectCommand = cmd
        }

        adapter.Fill(data)

        CmbLoanAvail.ValueMember = "loancode"
        CmbLoanAvail.DisplayMember = "loandescription"
        CmbLoanAvail.DataSource = data
    End Using
End Sub
```

You can use `SelectionChangeCommitted` event to execute some action when **user** made a selection

```
Private Sub comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles comboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted

    Dim combobox As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)

    Dim selectedCode As String = combobox.SelectedValue.ToString()  // returns 'loancode'
End Sub
```

Comment: Selected value gives output as string also what if the loan code will be LC001. Again to put value in the textbook you would require cast value as string.

Answer (score 0):

If you could get DB rows as strongly typed classes, you could make use of `ItemSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`, which would solve your problem.

In case you presented, you can use `SelectedIndex` property of `ComboBox`. Also, you need to store resultset in some class field (preferably `Pirvate` one). See example code below:

```
Public Class Form4
    Private _result As DataTable

    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("col1")
        dt.Columns.Add("col2")
        dt.Rows.Add("val11", "val12")
        dt.Rows.Add("val21", "val22")
        ' at this point, we got our result from DB
        _result = dt

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(row("col1"))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim selectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
        Dim selectedRow = _result(selectedIndex)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I think looping is not the good idea here as the another way of filling combo box is there.

Comment: @SurajKumar without any class defined it's hard to use `ItemsSource`, thus need for looping

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used so you can ensure that they are closed and disposed. Note the comma at the end of the first `Using` line. This includes the command in the same `Using` block.

Set the `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` after the Using block so the user interface code doesn't run until the connection is disposed.

To get the loan code you simply access the `SelectValue` of the `ComboBox`.

```
Private Sub LoanProducts()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using gSqlConn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT loancode,loandescription FROM LoanProducts", gSqlConn)
        gSqlConn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "loandescription"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "loancode"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    MessageBox.Show($"The Loan Code is {ComboBox1.SelectedValue}")
End Sub
```